# Linux Mail servers over Windows Mail servers

Tags: linux, email

am new in systems administration and the org am in has been using exchange 2003 for lyk forever,i thot i would change the systems to a linux server basically to cut l

Comment: New to the English language as well by the looks of it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, dear mr. new - please consider that you dont even know what you are talking about.

> has been using exchange 2003 for lyk forever

That would be "like" not "lyk", AND... Exchange 2003 is NOT A MAIL SERVER. What you try to do is like replacing a car with a spare engine. Exchange (2003 is outdated and seriously must be upgrades like yesterday) is a LOT more than a mere email system.

Unless your company does not use any of the othe features (like shared calendard, integration with phones in a push fasion) and has no interest in using some of the new featuers an upgrade would bring (voice control of calendar, integration with a SIP phone system as integrated mailbox with text to speech and speech to text) you basically are on the way to make a moronic bad decision. The type that may turn your system administration career with immediate termination for gross neglect and demosntrated incompetence.

So, sit down and think of what your company uses Exchange for. Then sit down and try tofind a product that can replace it in it's entierety. Then sit down and consider an ugparde (2010 is a LOT better than 2003). Then sit down and consider the assoiated costs for moving to linus in your company (which may include thigns like integrating backups, changing procesdures, adding more staff that has in depth linux knowledge etc.). Then make an educated decision. Right now you look like - sorry tobe blund - an ignorant linux zealot who does not even bother to check the software he wants to replace for the functionaltiy it offers.

MOST companies would really get angry with some junior wannabe system admin replacing their integrated staff coordination platform with a mere email system.

Comment: Don't let the trolls get to you, just flag the question and move on :)